# How to get Django LoginRequiredMixin working?

Tags: django

I'm working with Django 3 and I would like to restrict my views only to logged-in users. So I decided to implement Djangos method of LoginRequiredMixin, to controll access to my whole view. But this is not working in my view.

```
class UsersView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def user_list(request):
        users = adg_users.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'care/user/users.html', {'users': users})
```

The view is still open, although I'm not logged in. What could be the problem here?
What do I have to do to make it working?

In addition here is the urls.py to see how the view will be called:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('users/', UsersView.user_list, name='users'),
    path('login/', view.adg_login, name='login'),
    path('logout/', view.adg_logout, name='logout'),
]
```

Comment: You have to put `@login_required` above your each protected view

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `as_view()` method for your `UsersView` class:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('users/', UsersView.as_view(), name='users'),
    path('login/', view.adg_login, name='login'),
    path('logout/', view.adg_logout, name='logout'),
]
```